# I want to stream data using WCF as I am executing a data reader

Tags: wcf, ado.net

I don't want to read the whole thing, than put it in a file and than stream that. I wonder can I stream the datareader somehow to the client using WCF and Streaming on?

Comment: What have you attempted to achieve your requirement? Posting code usually helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using MessageContracts.

When I was trying to figure this out myself for the first time, I came across this article, which really helped a lot: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP

Here is a very basic example of setting up your Contract:

```
[MessageContract]
public class MyFileInfo : IDisposable
{

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string FileName;

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public long Length;

    [MessageHeader]
    public string FileHash;

    [MessageHeader]
    public string Status;


    [MessageBodyMember]
    public Stream FileData;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (FileData != null)
        {
            FileData.Close();
            FileData = null;
        }
    }
}

[MessageContract]
public class FileRequest
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public string fileName;

}
```

When I was first learning WCF I hated how verbose the default application config files were, so after some google searches / research I wrote a blog post w/ Code Examples on how to setup WCF Client proxy without a huge application config file: http://justindonohoo.blogspot.com/2012/08/generic-wcf-client-library-code.html